# Find the max of a sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I need some help in using the `sum` and `max` functions in SQL.

I want to display for each year, the month with the highest sales.

I have 2 tables

```
sales.orderline:
orderno - prodno - quantity - price - linetotal

sales.custorder:
orderno - custno - salesrep - orderdate
```

This is what I have:

```
select year(orderdate) as year, month(orderdate) as month, sum(linetotal) as sales
from sales.custorder 
inner join sales.orderline on sales.custorder.orderno = sales.orderline.orderno
where year(orderdate) is not null and month(orderdate) is not null
group by month(orderdate), year(orderdate)
```

My problem is that this shows the total for each month of the year and I don't know how to select only the month with the highest total for each year. My only idea was `max(sum())` which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`. Let's say that if you have two months with same sales in a year then you can use `dense_rank()`.

```
select
  year,
  month,
  sales
from
(
  select 
    year(orderdate) as year, 
    month(orderdate) as month, 
    sum(linetotal) as sales,
    row_numbe() over (partition by year(orderdate) order by sum(linetotal) desc) as rnk
  from sales.custorder sc
  inner join sales.orderline so
  on sc.orderno = so.orderno
  where year(orderdate) is not null 
  and month(orderdate) is not null
  group by 
    month(orderdate), 
    year(orderdate)
) val
where rnk = 1

order by
  year,
  month
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions, if your database supports them:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        year(orderdate) as yr, 
        month(orderdate) as mn, 
        sum(linetotal) as sales,
        rank() over(partition by year(orderdate) order by sum(linetotal) desc) rn
    from sales.custorder 
    inner join sales.orderline on sales.custorder.orderno = sales.orderline.orderno
    where year(orderdate) is not null and month(orderdate) is not null
    group by month(orderdate), year(orderdate)
) t
where rn = 1
order by yr
```

Note that `rank()` allows top ties, if any.

Unrelated: condition `year(orderdate) is not null and month(orderdate) is not null` can probably be simplified as `orderdate is not null`.